# Can someone move my car if it's in Park?

Tags: automatic-transmission, parking

If I'm parked on the side of the street, is it possible for someone or a group of people to move my car by pushing it for example? My car is an automatic and it was on Park with no hand-brake on packed snow/ice.

**Setting** : My car got a ticket for parking in front of a driveway. I'm 99% sure I didn't park in front of that driveway as when I parked, there was a lot of other places on the street and the driveway in question is really hard to miss. Before pleading not guilty I am trying to figure out if it's possible my car was moved by someone. Police said that I was in front of a driveway and that my car was so close to someone that they were not able to move, which wasn't the case when I parked there in the first place and when I got to my car there was no car around mine. My guess is that someone thought I boxed them in and pushed me in front of a driveway with their car.

Comment: If your car was pushed by another car there will be signs on the bumper. Something crushed or smooshed and paint transfer from the other car.

Answer (score 1):

Cars are slideable even if in park, when standing on level snow/ice. It's not easy (the pushers have poor traction, too) but it's a lot easier than when the car's on dry pavement.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the OPs concept that someone pushed the car into the driveway path. There are YouTube videos of tow truck drivers pulling vehicles in Park, while one wheel spins in reverse during the tow. Especially being on ice would make it that much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Does not even need to be pushed or slid - 4 or 5 men can easily pick up a small car and move it...

Did it with 4 others at school when we moved a teacher’s car so we were only 15 at the time but all in the rugby team... wish I still had those muscles...